# How can I view unformatted drives in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Sorry if this question is a bit novice but I am still learning about linux based systems. Thanks in advance!

So I have a computer I am doing some experimenting with. So to start, I Set up a USB stick with the latest Ubuntu (14.04.1) using PendriveLinux and that seems to be get me operational on the laptop to some extent.

Before installing ubuntu on the pc I wanted to view the hard drive. So I am unable to mount it and running "sudo fdisk -l" states that it does not have a partition table. I assume this is because I need to format it. Is that true?

With this in mind my question is, can I view the the drive without formatting it first?

Comment: have you given GParted a try?

Comment: *"...it does not have a partition table"* -- If no partitions are detected, then no filesystems can be mounted.  If you want to look at raw sector data, then there's the `dd if=/dev/sda of=sector_dump count=1` command (and view the data in the created file with `hexdump`).

Answer (score 0):

it might depend where you are trying to mount it. You might be running into permission issues, try running:

```
mkdir ~/mount
```

then

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxx ~/mount
```

and finally

```
sudo naultilus
```

The first command will create a folder in the live user home directory, where you will be mounting your HD.

The second one is the actual mounting taking place, however the `/dev/sdxx` might be different for you, for example, when you do `fdisk -l`, your HD could appear as `/dev/sda`.

The third command is to run the file explorer as root, since we mounted the HD with root privileges and isnt visible by normal users. So with nautilus, navigate to the live user's home and find the `mount` folder and see if your HD's contents is inside.

This answer is assuming the HD isn't empty, if it is empty, then you must format it, yes.

Comment: All that you wrote is very helpful and may well be part of the next steps for me. The last line of your reply, how can I tell if it  empty or not?

Comment: Well for one, have you ever used it? And running `df -h` will show the filesystem's available on the workstation and it's disk usage in human readable form.

Comment: xR34P3Rx, This drive has been sitting around for a  bit and I don't remember if I ever did anything with it before. So I just did a simple format on it trying to see what would be made available. Now the drive does show when I do "df -h" but says there is 68M used already. Would this used space be the partition table? When I look at the drive now nothing is visible on it.

Comment: "Simple format" is a bit vague, what format did you use? Ext3/4? NTFS? Fat system perhaps? It might depends on the format issued for the 64 mb being used but yes, possibly the partition table. I would format it based on what you want to use the hd for.

Comment: Ubuntu called it a quick format, not erasing the whole drive. The format i chose was NTFS.

Comment: Go into `gparted`, it's a gui based partition manager. Select your hd from the top right, delete all partitions. Will you be installing an os on this hd?

Comment: Yes, installing Ubuntu is the end goal. Im just doing some looking around as I go to understand things better.

Comment: OK, i reviewed your op. For Linux, use ext 4 journaled. Create a swap partition of your choice, 2048mb is ok